# Which Keycloak flow for the client-side authentication of an SPA?

Tags: nuxt.js, keycloak

I'm trying to build client-side authentication for a Nuxt app (backend is a Laravel API) using Keycloak but am facing several issues.

When using the standard flow for my client, it sets cookies in my browser but Chrome warns me in the console that third-party cookies will be blocked in just a few months.

So I tried using the direct access grants flow. It seems a bit awkward to me to have to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type in my request but why not. I get the JWT. But later found this [forum post](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/request-access-token-with-content-type-application-json/9621) where a Keycloak person says that this flow won't allow SSO and is also considered less secure.

So which flow should I use ? I need an auth system that will remain valid in the long run and allows SSO.